# Failed to build gem native extension mimemagic + rake failed, exit code 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

hi guys its actually my first install and I don't know what can I do?

[this is the terminal response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnF0A.jpg)

I tried to update rake

I tried to install only mimemagic (just as terminal red text)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code as links, please put the code directly in your question. And please post text code, not pictures of code.

Comment: It couldn't find "freedesktop.org.xml" in your PATH variables.